# How to create a file or folder and the same time write it to the .sh file

Tags: bash

How to create a file or folder and the same time write it to the .sh file?

For example: word count for a file, write that info to a new file and save it in the .sh file at the same time.

I tried:

```
echo 'wc filename.txt > ./folder/newfilename.txt' >>ToThefilename.sh
```

it would give me the word count for file name in the folder, but in the sh file it would give me what's on the quotes.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example? What should "ToTheFilename.sh" look like?

Comment: the results of the commands instead of what I typed in quotes

Comment: Right. So please update your question to include a code block that shows us an example of that.

Comment: @user251427 Did you mean to write output of `wc filename.txt` run from a `.sh` file to another text file at `./folder/newfilename.txt`?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What exactly do you want to write in the `ToThefilename.sh` file? If you mean the output of `wc filename.txt > ./folder/newfilename.txt` this is always null if the command ends with success. So, nothing to write in `ToThefilename.sh` file...

Answer (score 4):

Echo will print whatever you've given it in quotes, literally. So

```
echo 'wc filename.txt > ./folder/newfilename.txt' >>ToThefilename.sh
```

Should append this text to the end of `ToThefilename.sh`

> wc filename.txt > ./folder/newfilename.txt

If you want to write the output of `wc filaname.txt` to "ToThefilename.sh" you'd just do `wc filename.txt >>ToThefilename.sh` So if I do `wc examples.desktop > foo.txt` then `foo.txt` will contain the results of that command:

```
amanda@mona:~$ cat foo.txt 
 240  569 8980 examples.desktop
```

if you just want to keep a log of things you've done to or with `filename.txt` you can do `history | grep filename.txt > ToThefilename.sh`

If that isn't what you're trying to accomplish, please clarify your question! To do something more complex, you're probably going to need to write a shell script that takes the input and does a few different things with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `tee` and a process substitution:

```
echo 'wc filename.txt' | tee >(bash > ./folder/newfilename.txt) >> ToThefilename.sh
```

The process substitution acts like a file for the tee command. tee will pipe the output of the echo command to both the file and to stdout (where the redirection appends it to the script). bash will read the command on its stdin